# Is there a clean solution to achieve inclusive start, exclusive end in QueryDSL / Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, querydsl

I am trying to create a query for a time interval using QueryDSL (inclusive start, exclusive end date).

In the [documentation](http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/2.1.2/apidocs/com/mysema/query/types/expr/ComparableExpression.html#between(T,%20T)) of QueryDSL I found that the `public BooleanExpression between(Expression<T> from, Expression<T> to);` is exclusive on both sides,

> Get a first < this < second expression

however it translates to Oracle SQL `BETWEEN` which is inclusive on both sides 
(equivalent to `first <= this <= second`).

a QueryDSL like this:

```
[...]
person.name.like(n)
  .and(person.birthdate.between(from, to))
[...]
```

translates to Oracle SQL like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM PERSON
WHERE NAME LIKE n
  AND BIRTHDATE BETWEEN from AND to;
```

Does anybody know the reasons/logic behind this?
Is it just the 'rotten' documentation?

Clearly the between won't work for me niether way.

Should I rather use the more clunky

```
person.name.like(n)
  .and(person.birthdate.goe(from)
  .and(person.birthdate.lt(to))
```

or is there a clean solution that does what I want?

Comment: If this was plain SQL I'd use `between "from" and "to" - 1`?  (assuming `to_` is a `DATE` value

Comment: That only works if the dates are all truncated @a_horse; the OPs actual request would be `between "from" and "to" - interval '1' second`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation has been fixed already some time ago http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/2.2.0/apidocs/com/mysema/query/types/expr/ComparableExpression.html#between(T,%20T)

2.2.0 was released on 18.7.2011. I strongly recommend that you use a newer version of Querydsl from either 4.* or 3.*.

For inclusive start, exclusive end you can write your own utility method:

```
public static <T> Predicate range(ComparableExpression<T> expr, T from, T to) {
    return expr.goe(expr).and(expr.lt(to));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This does appear to just be shoddy documentation, however, I don't think it makes that much difference. If the documentation did what's suggested then it would be inappropriate for you; what's happening currently is slightly better.

There isn't a single expression in Oracle's SQL dialect that will represent the operation `first <= this < second`. Thus, you'd still have to do something like this:

```
person.name.like(n)
  .and(person.birthdate.between(from, to)
  .and(person.birthdate.lt(to))
```

which would be represented in SQL as:

```
select *
  from person
 where name like n
   and birthdate between from and to
   and birthdate < to
```

At that point it's just as easy to state your intentions clearly up-front and do what you're intending:

```
person.name.like(n)
  .and(person.birthdate.goe(from)
  .and(person.birthdate.lt(to))
```

---

P.S. I'm a little surprised that `column.like(String)` becomes `column like string` in SQL; this is equivalent to `column = string`. I would have expected `.like()` to become `column like string || '%'`, which would search at the beginning of the column for the string you're asking for.